# Spring Error creating bean with name 'covidController' defined in file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, architecture, spring-data-jpa

First of all, you may think/vote this question as a duplicate. Let me tell you, I have tried almost every possible solution on SO and not on SO.

I am using the Spring framework for a project and the project is based on a layered architecture. I have tried to fix an exception that is thrown when I start the Spring. I am trying to solve this for the last few days and I was not able to solve it. (I am new to spring)

I have three layers:

- domain
- persistence
- rest

When I start the application, it throws me an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'covidController' defined in file [......./layered-architecture-spring/rest/target/classes/com/comp/rest/CovidController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'covidRepository' defined in com.comp.persistence.CovidRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on RestApp: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.comp.persistence.CovidRepository.fetchAllData()! No property fetchAllData found for type Covid!
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.comp.persistence.CovidRepository.fetchAllData()! No property fetchAllData found for type Covid!
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fetchAllData found for type Covid!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
```

My whole project on GitHub: https://github.com/Phoenix404/ssa-layered-assignment

```java
@RestController
public class CovidController {

    private final CovidRepository covidRepository;

    public CovidController(CovidRepository cr) {
        covidRepository = cr;
    }

    @GetMapping("/cdata")
    public List<Covid>  getList() {
        return this.covidRepository.findByLocation("italy");
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface CovidRepository extends JpaRepository<Covid, Integer> {

    List<Covid> fetchAllData();

    List<Covid> findByDate(Date date);

    List<Covid> findByLocation(String location);

}
```

`CovidController` is my Rest app controller inside the rest module. The `CovidRepository` is in the persistence module.

I am using the following annotations for scanning the classes as suggested on other SO but I am still getting the error:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.comp.**persistence**")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.comp.**"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.comp.**"})



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.comp.persistenc*")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.comp"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.comp"})



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.comp.*")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.comp.*"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.comp.*"})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `findAll` instead of `fetchAllData` in `CovidRepository`. Also, delete that method from repository.

Comment: Thanks, the app started successfully but I can see any record `http://localhost:8080/cdata/`...

Comment: Quickly went through your app this is the root cause of the application `Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available`

Comment: By removing the methods from Repository, the app runs successfully but, I am not able to fetch the data.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @aniket-sahrawat, for solving the question.

The problem is solved, when I removed the methods from my `covidRepository`.